# (https)Nginx --> (http)Play!. But request.secure is false

Tags: nginx, playframework

Configured Nginx as reverse proxy in front of Play! and passing https 
with the following headers set :-

```
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https; 
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl https;
```

`login()` [`https://localhost/login`] is being forwarded to Play! on port 
9000 as 'http'. But request.secure in login() is still 'false'. Any idea ?

UPDATE:
here is the server conf:-

```
server {
    listen                443;
    server_name           localhost;

    ssl                   on;
    ssl_certificate       /home/aymer/play/key/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /home/aymer/play/key/localhost.key;
    ssl_session_timeout   5m;

    location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
            root    /home/aymer/play/playapp/public;
            expires 30d;
    }

    location ~* (login|register)$ { 
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:9000;
            proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl    on;
        }

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) http://$host/$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show complete `server {}` config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the second entry is wrong, it should be:

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
```

That will solve the issue

UPDATE: without being able to test, the only thing I see missing is this header:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Besides that, everything seems correct.

Comment: Dug a bit to play.mvc.Http.Request class. In addition to setting XFF header, I had to add, XForwardedSupport=<proxy server address> in the application.conf file. For eg: in my case, XForwardedSupport=127.0.0.1. Its working now.

Comment: Note: Play 2.5 seems to ignore the headers and only check whether request.uri starts with `https` to set the `request.secure` value

Answer (score 3):

Just to make things clear. I ran on this issue and had a bit of an hard time to have the complete working solution.

To make it work, your nginx configuration must contains :

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl    on;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

The parameter

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
```

is useless (for this use case).

BUT you also need to have this specified in your application.conf :

```
XForwardedSupport=<proxy server address> # generally, 127.0.0.1
```

This answer is just a recap of the whole conversation between Pere Villega and Aymer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the solution would be to change:

```
"proxy_redirect     off;"
```

into

```
"proxy_redirect     http://localhost https://localhost;"
```

`"localhost"` being the value for server_name.